# Laravel 5 - Model Id not updating proprely in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel

I am relatively new to Laravel and I am trying to print an "edit" button and a "remove" button on a page that would remove the corresponding item from the database. The items are organized in table rows, the buttons at the end of each row.

I am doing something like this:

```
     @foreach(Auth::user()->events as $event) [...]
 <div style="display: table-cell; float: right; padding-right: 10px">
                        {!! Form::model($event, ['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['EventController@destroy',$event->id]]) !!}
                        {!! Form::submit('Remove Event', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell; float: right; padding-right: 10px ">
                        <a href="{{action('EventController@edit', [$event->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Event</a><br><br>
                    </div>[...]
@endforeach
```

The second button (the Edit) is correctly pointing to the "id" of my events, for each event.

The first button (remove event) however is stubbornly pointing to the id of the first event in my list, for ALL the events. If I print $event->id before the first Form tag, it returns correctly the different event ids on each row. Appreciate if someone could tell me what I am getting wrong! Thanks

Adding row HTML below. The link looks correct. A mouse hover on the "remove" button however points me to the wrong id (in this case "24" for all rows).

```
                        <div style="display: table-cell; float: right; padding-right: 10px">
                        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/events/25" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="EDyShblSllVX1Zr992saX4YPAXxh05p8UiVGmDkF">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Remove Event">
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell; float: right; padding-right: 10px ">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8888/events/25/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Event</a><br><br>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What does this code generate? (can you post the raw HTML generated by this blade template?)

Comment: Use `open` instead of `model`.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, what would be the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `{{Form::close()}}`, which is why this is happening. Make sure to insert this after each`Form::model()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worth pointing out that the manual page for `Form::model()` contains a big red warning box urging you to always use `Form::close()` after using `Form::model()`.